# Fitting an ellipse such that the ratio of its radii is in a range

Tags: conic-sections, regression

I need to fit an ellipse to a group of points. However, I have an issue and I appreciate if anyone can help me. The issue is that I need to have the fitted ellipse such that the ratio of its radii is not too big or too small (is in a known range). For example see the below figure. Ellipse 1 in this figure is the ellipse that the fitting algorithm finds. It seems that it somehow tries to find the smallest possible ellipse. However, I need to find something like Ellipse 2. Basically I need to avoid any big change in the slope of the boundary of the ellipse, or in other words, the ratio of its radii not too big or too small. As it is clear in the figure, the ratio of the radii of the Ellipse 1 is much bigger (as its horizontal radius is too small) than that of Ellipse 2.

I am using the following algorithm in Matlab which is from the article "Numerically stable direct least squares fitting of ellipses".

I very much appreciate any suggestion/solution.

[image]

The algorithm:

```
 function a = fit_ellipse(x, y)
 D1 = [x .^ 2, x .* y, y .^ 2]; % quadratic part of the design matrix
 D2 = [x, y, ones(size(x))]; % linear part of the design matrix
 S1 = D1' * D1; % quadratic part of the scatter matrix
 S2 = D1' * D2; % combined part of the scatter matrix
 S3 = D2' * D2; % linear part of the scatter matrix
 T = - inv(S3) * S2'; % for getting a2 from a1
 M = S1 + S2 * T; % reduced scatter matrix
 M = [M(3, :) ./ 2; - M(2, :); M(1, :) ./ 2]; % premultiply by inv(C1)
 [evec, eval] = eig(M); % solve eigensystem
 cond = 4 * evec(1, :) .* evec(3, :) - evec(2, :) .^ 2; % evaluate a’Ca
 a1 = evec(:, find(cond > 0)); % eigenvector for min. pos. eigenvalue
 a = [a1; T * a1]; % ellipse coefficients
 end
```

Comment: Have a look at "Régressions coniques, quadriques, circulaire, ..." by JJacquelin at http://www.scribd.com/JJacquelin/documents. It is in French but easy to follow. It is a very simple approach.

Comment: Where in this document you are referring to? Does it have anything related to my question or it is just general information about curve fitting?

Comment: There is a part entitled "régressions coniques" which gives a very simple way of fitting for ellipses.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but then how can I include the constraint of the ratio as I explained in my question?

Comment: This is pure conjecture on my part, but since an ellipse is symmetrical, could you just estimate the "top half", (e.g. by making the y values all positive) and running a regression $y=ax^2 + bx+C$ and imposing the restrictions you need? Again, I have no idea if this is valid or would even work.

Comment: You can turn the problem to minimizing the sum of squares with constraints; $lsqlin$ is suppose to handle them. One of the variable should be the ratio of the radii; another will be one of the radii.